# add active class to link with sf2 and twig doesn't work

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to add the active class option in twig But it doesn't work..

```
<li class="{% if app.request.get('_route') == 'profile-edit' %}active{% endif %}"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
```

Comment: Output {{ app.request.get('_route') }} to test what is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Symfony 2.3` I have used `app.request.attributes.get('_route')`. It returns route name.

```
<li class="{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'profile-edit' %}active{% endif %}">
   <a href="#">Profile</a>
</li>
```

**UPDATED:**

I suggest you have used `forward` method in the controller. Try change your logic or send `route name` to the forwarded controller.

Comment: Thanks For all your elps Bro :)

Answer (score 1):

the place you got the code from assumes you will replace the second part with something dynamic

`{{ app.request.get('_route') }}` return something like `/route/with/filled/in/params/id-123/`

best way is to compare it agains another generated route like so

```
<li class="{% if app.request.get('_route') == path('acme.my_route_name)active{% endif %}"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
```